# Correct usage of wh-pronoun

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

I am facing problem regarding the usage of *who* and *whom*. So I want to know how to use those pronouns?
For example: *who* or *whom* do you think I met?

Comment: 'Who' is used as the **subject** of the verb. For examples, see the answer from @sooeithdk. 'Whom' is used as the **object** of the verb *or preposition*. An example: "For whom was this done?"

Comment: Here is the best explanation I have ever seen: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/who_vs_whom

Comment: +1 for the oatmeal, really good explanation.  Also it's worth noting that no one really uses whom in spoken English these days...

Answer (score 0):

If that who is doing the action, you use who.

> He was the man who became wealthy by selling medicine.

If that who is not doing any action, you muse use whom.

> He was the man whom I met yesterday.

Also, when using it as pronoun, you follow the same rule.

> Whom do you think I met yesterday?

Comment: This question already has an answer here:
_What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?_ And seems to have been asked more times than any other on ELU.